# What can I do if I set myself on fire to stop being fire?

Tags: assassins-creed-origins

It's pretty easy to set yourself on fire in Assassin's Creed Origins. Just take a torch too close to wood or get too close to campfire, and you can easily burst into flames.

Once you're on fire, you just burn to death in seconds. Is there a way to avoid that gruesome fate?

Comment: The logical solution would be to stop, drop, and roll

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Multiple posts seem to claim that pressing the dodge button will help extinguish the fire:

[GameFAQS](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/211211-assassins-creed-origins/76148101):

> keep tapping the dodge/evade button if not near water.

A [Steam Post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/582160/discussions/0/1480982971171147463/#c1480982971171149736):

> Hit space bar or your dodge button to dodge, it douses the flame faster

Another [Steam Post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/582160/discussions/0/1483235412208174708/#c1483235412209435187):

> You just have to mash the dodge button a few times. The game only really explains this via a tip on the loading screens.

And unsurprisingly, jumping into water will do the job as well, but you will obviously need to be near a body of water.

Comment: The only downside of fast loading screens is missing helpful advice like this... but thinking about it makes sense.

Comment: Technically you should roll not just dodge. To roll you do a double press of dodge/evade -- one tap then a hold. Repeatedly dodging does nothing, but a roll will always extinguish you.

Answer (score -1):

Once you have set yourself on fire, open the map, choose any synchronization point, and **fast travel**.

Logically, this will not work during a battle.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work for others? Your answer, in addition to the existing answer, is to fast travel, right? If in your experience that works, just leave it at that, and you have a proper answer. (I've edited those comments out.)

Comment: ok, agree, accepted comment